# How to restrict tagged content based on user?

Tags: users, taxonomy-terms

I'm using drupal 7.39, but I don't know how to restrict users to access some specific content.

I have created a content type called **person**. Then I have created 5 nodes, like so:

- 2 nodes tagged with **manager** term.
- 2 nodes tagged with **lead** term.
- 1 node tagged with **worker** term.

This is where I struggle:

- the **worker** user must see node tagged with **worker**.
- the **lead** user must see node tagged with **lead** and **worker**.
- the **manager** user should see all nodes.

Is there any solution to get this to work (without writing custom code)? Because a configurable job is always easier.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like using the [Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) module is the most straight forward solution to answer your question. Some details about this module (from its project page):

> Access control for user roles based on taxonomy categories (vocabulary, terms).
>
> - Automatically controls access to nodes (based on their taxonomy terms).
> - Configuration page for each user role.
> - Three node access permission types: View, Update, Delete.
> - Two term access types: View tag, Add tag.

Together with using this module, you should also define 3 roles, i.e.:

- ***Lead***, granted to any user considered as "Lead".
- ***Worker***, granted to any user considered as "Worker".
- ***Manager***, granted to any user considered as "Manager".

With those roles and permissions in place, you have everything to configure your access rules as provided by the [Taxonomy Access Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) module.

PS: note that this has nothing to do with content type "Person" (as in your question). Not sure why you need/use that content type, but to get the above to work you don't need that.